# Proof of Karamata Inequality/Hardy-Littlewood Inequality.

Tags: inequality

Can anyone provide the proof for the Karamata Inequality?

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?highlight=majorization+karamata&t=14975

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality